# Pyspark self join to create network data

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, self-join

I have a spark table with 30 Million observations.

```
DF = sc.parallelize([ 
[('comp1'),('P1'), '2016-01-01'],
[('comp1'),('P4'),'2015-01-01'],
[('comp2'),('P1'),'2017-01-01'],
[('comp2'),('P2'),'2015-01-01'],
[('comp2'),('P4'),'2016-01-01'],
[('comp3'),('P3'),'2014-01-01'],
[('comp1'),('P2'),'2016-01-01'],
[('comp3'),('P2'),'2017-01-01']
]).toDF(["company", "Project",'Date'])
DF.show()
```

I want to create a directed network dataset to count the movement of each project between companies during last 5 years. when I do a self join on my table, it creates edges that are not in the dataset:

```
DF.alias('l').join(DF.alias('r'), on='Project')\
.where('r.Date > l.Date')\
.select(F.col('l.company').alias('company1'), 
F.col('r.company').alias('company2'), 'l.Project')\
.show()

+--------+--------+-------+
|company1|company2|Project|
+--------+--------+-------+
|   comp1|   comp2|     P1|
|   comp1|   comp3|     P2|
|   comp2|   comp1|     P2|
|   comp2|   comp3|     P2| #This is wrong
|   comp1|   comp2|     P4|
+--------+--------+-------+
```

I tried to create a counter and add another condition to my where clause:

```
DF =DF.withColumn("row_num", 
F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Project"))).orderBy('Project', 
'Date')

DF.alias('l').join(DF.alias('r'), on='Project')\
.where(('r.Date > l.Date')& ('r.row_num  - l.row_num < 2' ))\
.select(F.col('l.company').alias('company1'), 
F.col('r.company').alias('company2'), 'l.Project')\
.show()
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

How can I change my criteria in Where clause to correct this?

I am working on the cluster and cannot install libraries and I have only networkx installed and my Spark version is 1.6

Comment: Can you post the equivalent Pandas code?

Comment: @pissall please look at the link below:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979480/how-can-i-efficiently-create-a-user-graph-based-on-transaction-data-using-python

Comment: Aren't you satisfied with the dictionary performance? In Pyspark you just need to get 2 dataframes, join them on Project and date, call a `groupby count()` on company1_col, company2_col

Comment: @pissall Self join wouldn't work here because it creates edges that are not actually in the data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to create the output I was looking for:

```
df_lag = DF.withColumn('comp1',F.lag(DF['company']).\
                   over(Window.partitionBy("Project")))\
.filter(~F.isnull(F.col('comp1'))).select(F.col('comp1'), 
F.col('company').alias('comp2'),F.col('project')).show()


+-----+-----+-------+
|comp1|comp2|project|
+-----+-----+-------+
|comp1|comp2|     P1|
|comp2|comp1|     P2|
|comp1|comp3|     P2|
|comp1|comp2|     P4|
+-----+-----+-------+
```